# Is the usage of "Adequate" right in this context?

Tags: word-usage, meaning

I checked Cambridge dictionary and it defined 'adequate' as "Enough or satisfactory for a particular purpose". I want to use the word as a synonym for 'enough'. So, is it right in this context:

> "All this absurd hate will not be adequate to talk me out of my decision!"

Comment: "adequate" is like *sufficient*, while "enough" is like *no more*. In your example, use *enough*. "His knowledge is *sufficient* (adequate) to do the job" vs. "I have had enough of (I don't want any more of) your lies." For learning purposes you might look at other examples.

Comment: Refer to [*Synonyms of 'enough'*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/enough#enough__1).

Comment: +1 @user3169 "Adequate" can imply "mediocre" or "barely sufficient", and it is not the adjective a native speaker would use in your sentence. We might say instead simply _"All this absurd hate will not talk me out of my decision!"_

Comment: No candy or flowers, please.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, this is fine.  It's a more grandiose word than "enough", but fits with the usage of "absurd hate" to further strengthen the speaker's position on the subject.

Comment: grandiose? If i were to ask, how often is 'adequate' used as a synonym for enough?

Comment: @HoyHoy There is nothing "grandiose" about the adjective _adequate_. The answerer might benefit from consulting an English dictionary to learn the meaning of "grandiose"; _adequate_ hardly fits the bill.